# How to setup absolute positioning for ajax generated images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to setup absolute postion for all the images that are generated by ajax.

Here are my codes,

```
for loop...

  var imagediv = document.getElementById('image_layout');

//generate many images
  imagediv.innerHTML=  imagediv.innerHTML + "<div class='imgDiv'>" + "<a href=\"#\""><img src=\"" + mystuff.list[n].imgPath \"" + "\" )\"" + "></a></div>";

//The image shows correctly but I want to set all of them in absolute position so I can create other effects.
```

I am not sure how to do it and appreciate if anyone can help me out here. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You can do this with just CSS. `.imgDiv img{position:absolute;}`

Comment: @ahren yes I know, but my loop will generated many images and all of them will be stacked, not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any AJAX going on, but in any case if you're using jQuery then take full advantage of it:

```
var imgs = []
var $wrap = $('#image_layout')

for ( ... ) {
  imgs.push(
    "<div class='imgDiv'>"+
      "<a href='#'><img src='"+ mystuff.list[n].imgPath +"'/></a>"+
    "</div>"
  )
}

// Append everything at last for best performance
$wrap.append(
  $(imgs.join(''))
    .css('position', 'absolute')
)
```

Comment: Ty. The codes will make my images absolute but they will all stacked together. Are there any ways to fix that? +1

Comment: Of course they will, that's what position absolute does, you might want to float the images instead...

Comment: hm..I need to make all images absolute and well placed like Google image engine. guess I have to calculate the position with other codes....

Comment: Yeah but `position: absolute` is not what you're looking for. In fact `position: absolute` is rarely used for layouts, use `float: left` or `display: inline-block` instead, or a grid system like 960gs or even twitter bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you. This is the effect I wanted to created and he uses absolute position and I don't think float:left will acheive the same effect......http://nutnics.com/so/hover-zoom.php

Comment: Mmm... By looking at the code it seems that he's using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), that's probably what you're lookin' for...